# How to dynamically add queue to exchange in Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

I have the following exchange in **integrationcontext.xml**

```
<!-- rabbit exchanges, queues, and bindings used by this app -->
<rabbit:topic-exchange name="newPaymentEventsExchange" auto-delete="false" durable="true">
    <rabbit:bindings>

    </rabbit:bindings>
</rabbit:topic-exchange>
```

I need to be able to **dynamically** add queues to the exchange based on values of **channelName** from the following object from the database, also I should be able to update when someone adds a new channel:

```
public class Channel {
    private Long channelId;
    private String tenantId;
    private String channelName;

    ------
    //Getters & setters
 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `AmqpAdmin` to perform this kind of operations:

```
/**
 * Declare the given queue.
 * @param queue the queue to declare.
 * @return the name of the queue.
 */
String declareQueue(Queue queue);

/**
 * Declare a binding of a queue to an exchange.
 * @param binding a description of the binding to declare.
 */
void declareBinding(Binding binding);
```

You may consider to use `QueueBuilder` and `BindingBuilder` for convenience:

```
QueueBuilder.nonDurable("foo")
    .autoDelete()
    .exclusive()
    .withArgument("foo", "bar")
    .build()
...
BindingBuilder.bind(
            marketDataQueue()).to(marketDataExchange()).with(marketDataRoutingKey)
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration